# Why was Post Request not allowed in my Spring RestController?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I created a RestController with a Post method. Somehow when I made post request http://localhost:8080/api/users from Postman, It threw 405 method not allowed error.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
  public class RestRegistrationController {

    @PostMapping("/users")
    public GenericResponse registerUserDTo(@Valid @RequestBody UserDto user) {

        return new GenericResponse("success");
    }

}
```

My request post

```
{
    "firstName":"Test",
    "password":"Pa$$w0rd",
    "lastName":"Test",
    "email":"test2@test.com"
}
```

Comment: show what/how you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe error in Validation userDto object. Check all fiealds which coming via controller are the same as UserDto class

Comment: How is this even close to being an answer? How does validation logic yield a `405` response code unless of course you are doing something really terrible in your validation logic? I suggest using comments section for above **"!answer"**. Wait until you have gained enough points to answer a question. A down vote would only delay your **comment posting** previlage.

Answer (score 0):

If you does not define request method in the mapping the default is GET.

For POST:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/end-point-url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```